# How to debug Python script which is automatically called inside a web application?

Tags: python, debugging, cassandra, pdb, graphite

I'm developing a `cassandra` storage finder for `graphite-api`.
`graphite-api` is installed via pip and run via `gunicorn` so I can't just call the script with a debugger but want to use interactive debugging.

When I import `pdb` in my storage finder and set a breakpoint, the code will halt there, but how can I connect now to the headless running pdb in the script?
Or is my approach to this debugging problem the wrong one and this has to be done in a completely other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdb gives control over to gunicorn, which is not what you want. Have a look at rpdb or other remote debugging solutions.

Comment: rpdb was exactly what I was searching for. I looked at a few python remote debugging pages but none of them seemed to give me a useful remote debugging solution. rpdb halts the whole gunicorn worker process when running into rpdb.set_trace() and then I'm able to connect via netcat and start debugging. Useful information for any other user searching for this, you have to start gunicorn with a very high value for --timeout parameter because it kills hanging worker processes after 30secods